# Infinite scroll vuejs fired more than once

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll in my vue chrome extension. I have this code but the problem is that when the page bottom is reached, the ajax call to fetch new data is fired more than once. How i can fix?

```
  mounted() {
    this.$store.commit('preloader', false)
    window.onscroll = () => {
      if( window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight ){
        console.log('fired')
        this.nextPageLoaded = false 
        this.nextPage()
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextPage() {
      console.log('Loading next page')
      axios.get('https://localhost:8080/api/media')
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.$store.commit('profileMedia', response.data.media)
        this.nextPageLoaded = true
      })
    }
  }
```

I've tried by setting a variable `nextPageLoad` to true after data are loaded and on false when the scroll event reach the bottom but not work as expected. Any solution will be appreciaetd

Comment: Is it possible to create jsfiddle or codesandbox for the same?

Comment: Unfortunately the data I'm using are provided by my local dev server and I'm unable to replicate the same structure on a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's a typo but I don't see that you are actually using the `nextPageLoaded` property as a flag in the `if` statement.

It should be something like

```
mounted() {
  this.$store.commit('preloader', false)
  window.onscroll = () => {
    if ( (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight)  
          && !this.nextPageLoaded) {
      console.log('fired')
      this.nextPageLoaded = true 
      this.nextPage()
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  nextPage() {
    console.log('Loading next page')
    axios.get('https://localhost:8080/api/media')
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.$store.commit('profileMedia', response.data.media)
        this.nextPageLoaded = false
      })
  }
}
```

Also have in mind that I switched the values of the `nextPageLoaded` property assignments because I think it's more intuitive this way (assigns to `true` immediately after triggering the `nextPage` method, assigns to `false` after ending the AJAX call).

Comment: thanks for the help. I've modified the `if()` to add the `nextPageLoaded` variable and in my `data()` I've set it to an initial state of false. Now seems working all fine!